# Dot in file name?

Tags: image, filenames

Is it okay to use a "." (dot) in file names instead of camelcase or dashes etc.. for example:

```
ico_active.user.png
```

Will it cause any performance or browser compatibility issues or some other disadvantage?

Thanks!

Comment: As a completely useless piece of information: I consider `.` to have a lower priority than `_`, so I would mentally parse `ico_active.user` as the user of an active icon, rather than the icon of an active user. I would have written that as `ico.active_user.png` instead. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you save the response, then the last part will be used as the file name by some older browsers, but apart from that it's ignored. It used to be fun little joke to play on people to make a URI like ".jpeg" do something interactive because it was really a text/html with some javascript or flash, but these days people are too likely to know how it's done to serve as a prank any more.

IIS does have issues if the period is the final character of the URI, for reasons that escape me.

Answer (score 5):

Different OSes have different rules for filenames. For example, filenames cannot consist only of dots. In Windows filenames cannot end with a dot.

There is a convention where file types or formats trail dots; for example a something.tar.gz file is interpreted as the file or folder "something" that has been tar-ed then gzipped.

Dots are also problematic when matching filenames using regular expressions because . is a metacharacter while underscores and letters are not.

Comment: The names "." and ".." are reserved (for current directory and parent directory), but "..." and "...." are perfectly viable file names (or directory names) on Unix systems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.  It will look at the trailing .* for the "File Extension".

Answer (score 2):

**Dots in filenames...**

- *can* be somewhat problematic
- *certainly* make more work when processing filenames
- ***are* best avoided if you can!**

Consider:

1. A dot is used **as the separator** between base-filename and extension.
2. "." & ".." are reserved to represent the **current & parent directory**.
3. On *nix systems **a dot at the start of a filename** makes it a hidden file.

   - Thus on a Mac in Finder you are not allowed to give a file a name starting with a dot: [image: Mac Error]
4. On Windows you are not allowed to have **a dot at the end of a filename**

   - so dots at the end are simply removed
5. **Multiple dots**

   - *could* represent **multiple (embedded) extensions**, for example: something.tar.gz
   - *or* other information, like **version numbers**, for example: something_version.1.2.6.ext
6. When **copying files between different systems**

   - what works on one system may not on the other.
   - It is not possible to copy a file with a dot at the end of its name from mac to pc
   - It is not possible to copy a file with a dot at the beginning of its name from pc to mac

Unsurprisingly, certain programs have problems when files have dots in their names, for example:

- Mail apps cannot correctly, automatically link a file-with-a-dot-at-the-end in a text mail, because the trailing dot will be interpreted as the dot at the end of the sentence [image: Email link fail]
- FileMaker databases cannot correctly introspect, if they have dots in their names
- and many more!

Clearly the semantics of dots in filenames is quite complicated, confused & confusing.

Just.stay.away!

Answer (score 0):

Dot is about as safe a punctuation character as there is, except that many systems at least partially determine (assume?) the type of contents from what follows the last dot in the name.